# How to add contact in the list using sendgrid?

Tags: c#, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to add contact in the list so i'm using this link below to Add a Single Recipient to a List :
[click here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/USAGE.md#contactdb)

I have Advanced 100k plan and using full access api key but still getting forbidden error.

Please help me out in this.

**My code**

```
string data = @"[
  {
    'age': 25, 
    'email': 'example@example.com', 
    'first_name': '', 
    'last_name': 'User'
  }, 
  {
    'age': 25, 
    'email': 'example2@example.com', 
    'first_name': 'Example', 
    'last_name': 'User'
  }
]";
        var client = new SendGridClient("#################");
        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(data);
        data = json.ToString();
        var response = await client.RequestAsync(method: SendGridClient.Method.POST, urlPath: "contactdb/recipients", requestBody: data);
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
        return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by editing your API Keys settings in Send Grid and enabling the permissions for the features you need access to for that API Key.

[API Keys settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN7vC.png)